# Creating stacked bar chart using xlsxwriter

Tags: python, xlsxwriter, stacked-chart

I have columns listed below

[image]

With these columns, I need to display stacked bar chart with 'Month/Year' as x-axis, 'Count' as y-axis and 'Name' as the legend.
I tried this

```
chart1.add_series({
                    'name': '=Sheet1!$D$1',
                    'categories': '=Sheet1!$B$2:$B$3'),
                    'values': '=Sheet1!$B$2:$B$3'),
                    'fill': {'color': 'orange'})
chart1.add_series({
                    'name': ['Sheet1',0,4],
                    'categories' : ['Sheet 1',1,0,1,0],
                    'values' : ['Sheet1',1,3,2, 3],
                    'fill': {'color': 'orange'})
```

But I didn't get the expected output.
The expected output is : Sep-2021 in x-axis with Adam and Milne bars with values 6 and 3 respectively. And Legend with Adam and Milne

Comment: There are a number of issues with the code. In the first series the categories and values both point to the same range. In the second series the categories point to 1 cell instead of a range. It would probably be best to plot and arrange the chart you want in Excel first and then transfer over the ranges to the xlsxwriter program.